# How do you pronounce the word 任?

Tags: learning

I'm uncertain about the pronunciation of the word "任." Is it pronounced like "run" or more like "yen"? I've watched several videos, but I'm still unsure about the correct way to pronounce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial is a [Voiced retroflex fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_fricative) similar to the "r" in Spanish, i.e.: ratón [ʐa'ton] or the ږ in Southern Pashto dialects, e.g.: تږى [ˈtəʐai]. This is written in IPA as /ʐ/.

The final /ən/ can be found in English. For instance in the -on in butt**on** or in the -en- in fast**en**er.

You can use something like [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/%E4%BB%BB/#zh) to listen to real people pronounce characters like this.

Answer (score 2):

1. [rèn/ㄖㄣˋ] trust to; allow. (Words with the same pronunciation: 認, 刃, 飪)
2. [rén/ㄖㄣˊ] a surname. (Words with the same pronunciation: 人, 仁)

You can hear the pronunciation [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BB%BB).

Answer (score -2):

In mandarin(putonghua), 任 is pronounced like "learn"

In cantonese, 任 is pronounced like "yen"